# Explain What This Awk Command Does

Tags: awk

I have a portion of the VoIPBL update script.

```
cat /tmp/voipbl.txt | awk '{ print "if [ ! -z \""$1"\" -a \""$1"\"  != \"#\" ]; then /usr/sbin/ipset  -A voipbl_temp \""$1"\" ;fi;"}'
```

It creates lines like this:

```
if [ ! -z "1.2.3.4/32" -a "1.2.3.4/32"  != "#" ]; then  /usr/sbin/ipset -A voipbl_temp "1.2.3.4/32" ;fi; | sh
```

I understand the second part is adding a line from the file (IP) to an ipset, but what is the test condition doing? What does it mean when you have -z and -a in the same set of  brackets? And what does the not equal to "#" part mean?

Comment: That's not really an awk command - it's a shell command that just happens to be constructed using awk. Refer to the shell manual or `man test` to see what the brackets (and the `-a`) mean.

Answer (score 4):

It's reading presumably IPs from the `/tmp/voipbl.txt` file and then creating a shell if construct based on them.  The `$1` parameter from the awk script refers to the item in the first column on each line so the string in place of `1.2.3.4/32` will be that value in each iteration.

```
if [ ! -z "1.2.3.4/32" -a "1.2.3.4/32"  != "#" ]; then
```

`! -z "1.2.3.4/32"` - Is checking that `"1.2.3.4/32"` is not null.  `-z` checks if the string **is** zero but the `!` negates that.  This could and probably should be replaced with `-n` which just checks for not-null

`"1.2.3.4/32"  != "#"` - Is checking that `"1.2.3.4/32"` is not equal to `#` which I guess is something that could appear in your file.

The `-a` operator means **and**. So it's checking that the string is not null AND that it does not equal `#`.

If these conditions are met, the following will be executed:

```
/usr/sbin/ipset -A voipbl_temp "1.2.3.4/32"
```

To understand this better, try running the awk command on a file with the following contents:

```
1.2.3.4/32

# 3.4.5.6/32
```

If you now run your awk command on that file, you get:

```
$ awk '{ print "if [ ! -z \""$1"\" -a \""$1"\"  != \"#\" ]; then /usr/sbin/ipset  -A voipbl_temp \""$1"\" ;fi;"}' file
if [ ! -z "1.2.3.4/32" -a "1.2.3.4/32"  != "#" ]; then /usr/sbin/ipset  -A voipbl_temp "1.2.3.4/32" ;fi;
if [ ! -z "" -a ""  != "#" ]; then /usr/sbin/ipset  -A voipbl_temp "" ;fi;
if [ ! -z "#" -a "#"  != "#" ]; then /usr/sbin/ipset  -A voipbl_temp "#" ;fi;
```

The tests ensure that the `/usr/sbin/ipset` will only be run on the first line, with `1.2.3.4/32` and not on the other two.

Comment: Great explanation. It makes sense now. When I looked it up, I found that -a test can be a test for an existing file. That threw me off. So I guess that behavior is different when it's not a file name, and is just a string? Either way, thanks!

Comment: @d10nte: Yes, most people prefer to instead do something like:  `[ ! -z "1.2.3.4/32" ] && [ "1.2.3.4/32"  != "#" ]`.  Perhaps for that reason.

Comment: That would much clearer Jesse_b. I also agree with your comment on using "-n" rather than the other construct. Thanks for your help.